# drawImage(canvas) chrome size limit?

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a small part of a huge offscreen canvas (a buffer) into my canvas but I have an issue on chrome (works great of Firefox and IE).

The drawImage method doesn't work unless I reduce the size of my buffer by ~ 10%. My buffer is 12000x7500px, and it doesn't work unless I reduce it to 10000x6000px.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

I'm not providing a test case for now as it it not an easy one to create but I will if this issue isn't familiar to anyone here.

```
ctx.drawImage(game.bufferBackground,-eventManager.decalX,-eventManager.decalY,game.canvas.width, game.canvas.height, 0, 0, game.canvas.width, game.canvas.height);
```

ctx.canvas is 750px per 530px.
game.bufferBackground is 12000px per 7500px

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Split your big background to smaller tiles?

Comment: @Mikko you can also run into issues if you have too many canvases.

Answer (score -1):

Just ran into an issue with using drawImage in Chrome myself--make sure you size the canvas in the tag, not with CSS. When I size with CSS, only part of the image is drawn, but when I size using HEIGHT/WIDTH in the actual tag, it renders fine.

Example:

```
<canvas height="400" width="400">
```

not

```
<canvas style="height:400;width:400;">
```